# HTML & Javascript Spinner

Tags: javascript, html, css, coding-style, html-helper

I am creating a html spinner but having trouble with my code not playing the gif/timer once I've pressed stop and go. I have my html file in the folder with the gifs/png pictures buts its only showing one picture if the spinner and not actually going through the motion and spinning around once start is pressed.

Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Spinner</title>
        <style>
            body {text-align:center}
            </style>
            <script>
                var frame = 0;
                var timerID;
                var pics = new Array(12);
                function animate () {
                    document.images[0].src = pics[frame].src;
                    frame = (frame + 1)%12;
                    timerID = setTimeout ("animate()",100);
                }
                for (i=0; i<pics.length; i++) {
                    pics[i] = new Image();
                }
                for (var i=0; i<pics.length; i++) {
                    pics[i].src = "frame" + i + ".png";
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <img src="frame-1.png" alt="spinner"/>

            <form>
                <input type="button" value="Start" onclick='setTimeout("animate()",100);'/>
                <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick='clearTimeout(timerID);'/>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and this is what I keep getting in the screenshot but I need it to actually go around [Results im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gtm2.png)

I've tried playing around with the code more, but I'm not getting anything the full outcome im wanting which is having the spinner fully spin when I press stop.

Comment: First thing from where i is coming from you have to provide it with a datatype like let and second don't use var in the second loop use let.

Comment: Hey, just to double check, so you have a gif and you want to go through each frame (when start is clicked)of the gif and like iterate forever until you hit stop?

Comment: correct I am trying to get it to do that but I don't know what im missing @Ikura

Comment: I didn't really figure out a way but some people were able to get the gif to. be stopped initially and if you click on it it'll play and then stop will kind of reset it. https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/stop-autoplaying-your-gifs-stop-play-control.  , demo: http://krasimir.github.io/gifffer/
If you don't want to use a library you could always have the stop button like add a still version of your gif on top of your gif(that's not a great idea tbh but not sure what else, sorry :/, good luck!)